# Tracking, if my Page is opened as Tab

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I´m currently working on a little personal project, where I want to have a game related sign-in/up feature.

Every signed-up user on my page has the option to queue-up for an event over a button. When an user clicks the button, he queues up for an specific event. My backend should know send an ping to every queued up user (every few seconds) to determine if the user is still active queued up. To determine his activity I want to track my page/app state. If my page is opened somewhere in the browser (in a tab), the ping should return a true to tell my database, that the user is still queued up for the event. The ping should return a false, if it can not find my page opened (closed browser, shut down pc (crash) or closed tab).

I´m using C# with asp.net MVC

So I`m looking for a decent way to check my page state on the client side via a backend ping-solution.

Any hints in how to accomplish such an state-check? Would appreciate some hints.

Comment: Why not try the other way round - let the client update the backend to know it is still there? Take a look at [AJAX long-polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery/). Your backend then just needs to handle logic for the incoming AJAX requests, set a timeout to remove them from the queue if you didn't receive the AJAX request as expected.

Comment: Thy ... Will also take a look into this ;)

Comment: No problem - happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't be able to provide here a complete solution with code about how to solve the issue, but I can give you a hint to go forward and get yourself solving your requirement.

What you need is [*Web Sockets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and in .NET arena, one of easiest ways to get into the real-time client-server communication world is [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).

I would take a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) and how it works, and I assume you'll instantly figure out how to solve your issue.

About the thing of tracking if page is opened as tab, first of all I don't know about any modern Web browser which doesn't support tabs since years, so it would be useless working on this way. You just need to use a ping-pong approach to let the server know that some client is still alive independently of who's connecting to your endpoint (who cares if it's a Web app or a mobile app).

Comment: Thy for your answer, I was just looking for some hints to work myself on resolving the problem, just needed an entry, so thy.